# Directory-tree listing limiter Python

Tags: python, directory-tree

As title explains, I've tried several answers of already posted questions from this site. The thing is, that I'm trying to be able to select how much levels of the folder I dig into. For example, if I want to select only the immediate subdirectories it would look like this:

```
Subfolder #1
Subfolder #2
Subfolder #3
Subfolder #4
```

But if I want to the same but show also at the same the immediate subdirectories of the subdirectories already mentioned, it would look like this:

```
Subfolder #1
  Subfolder #1 of the subfolder #1
  Subfolder #2 of the subfolder #1
Subfolder #2
  Subfolder #1 of the subfolder #2
Subfolder #3
Subfolder #4
  Subfolder #1 of the subfolder #4
  Subfolder #2 of the subfolder #4
  Subfolder #3 of the subfolder #4
```

PD: I'm pretty new to Python, so I'm probably missing pretty obvious.

EDIT: I reformulated the question, so I can better explain my issue, since it was clearly confusing and did not make any sense the way I said it.

Comment: You mean like os.listdir()? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm. I guess your question is confusing because if you want a tree, then why would you only be interested in the immediate subdirectores. A tree implies that you are going through multiple levels of hierarchy...

Comment: I don't understand your question. What does it mean "a version without formatting"? To me it seems like the question you linked already answers your question. You want the "immediate subdirectories", but `os.walk` yields exactly that. At each iteration it yields the "current directory" a list of files and subdirectories. If you want the "immediate subdirectories" you simply have to stop at the first iteration: `for _, immediate_subdirectories, _ in os.walk(parent_dir)):break` or `next(os.walk(parent_dir))[1]`

Comment: @Spencer Well, the issue with os.listdir() is that it does not do it with a Directory-tree style, since that's the main point of my issue.

Comment: @racer21 Spencer's saying what you want is a listing of a directory (literally), not a tree. Are you just looking to get the output line-by-line? If so have you tried `for f in os.listdir(somedir): print(f)`? Otherwise could you [edit] the question and clarify, with some expected output?

Comment: The question has been completely reformulated, so I can better explain my issue.

Comment: I see now. Your question is a little confusing but I think I understand, gimme a second and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Do you only want directories, or files and directories?

Comment: @racer21 As Hampus correctly points out your edit would remove some intended functionality. Leaving `inspection_depth` means that you can easily choose how far this will dive into the folder structure. If you only want one level of depth then there is no reason to recurse. If this answer satisfies your question please hit that green check-mark! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly this should do what you want. It is a simple recursive function that just keeps a counter of how "deep" it has gone into the directory and completes when it hits the required number of recursions. Let me know if you need a little more explanation.

```
import os

search_dir = "path/to/dir"
inspection_depth = 1

def walk(path, depth):
    depth += 1
    folders = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, f))]

    for folder in folders:
        full_path = os.path.join(path, folder)
        print(full_path)

        if depth < inspection_depth:
            walk(full_path, depth)

# Call the recursive function
walk(search_dir, 0)
```